# Export a property using MEF

Tags: c#, mef, ioc-container

Let us consider the following scenario:

```
class Master
{
    private Person selectedPerson;

    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedPerson;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedPerson = value;

        }
    }

}

[Export(typeof(Details))]
class Details
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public Details(Person person)
    {

    }
}
```

I need to initialise an instance of Details with SelectedPerson as argument. So, basically, I need to inject a particular instance of  Person to the Details constructor.

How can I do that using MEF?

Comment: I dont believe that it possible with MEF, you should create a service that is able to load a person's details and then import that service into the details class. You could then use the available information from the person object, to load the correct details from the service. i.e var contactDetail = contactDetailService.Load(person.Id);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: You need to export the `Person` you want to inject. Here is a basic example of a possible console application:

```
public class Program
{
    [Export(typeof(Person))]
    private Person personToInject { get; set; }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().Run();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(".");
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        //Create the person to inject before composing
        personToInject = new Person();        

        container.ComposeParts(this);
    }
}
```

Note that the `ImportingConstructor` attribute is only allowed to use once a class.

To improve the solution you should use names to identify the properties to inject. Therefore you have to extend the prototype of your constructor

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public Details([Import("personParameter")]Person person)
```

and your export

```
[Export("personParameter")]
private Person personToInject { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help - happy coding :-)

Comment: How does the dependency injection framework know which instance of the class to use for dependency injection? Are all instances used?! What's the mechanism here or documentation on this?

Comment: The instance marked with the `Export` attribute is used.